# Trim multiple trailing and leading keyword off string MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, replace, trim

I have a table with data something like this

```
 ---------------
|town           |
 ---------------
|Longton North  |
|Longton South  |
|Longton North  |
|Longton East   |
|Longton West   |
|East Valley    |
|West Valley    |
 ---------------
```

I know how to trim trailing and leading chars from string by using

```
TRIM(BOTH 'North' FROM town)
```

But I want to trim North, South, West, East out of my result. So the output should be like

```
 ---------
|town     |
 ---------
|Longton  |
|Longton  |
|Longton  |
|Longton  |
|Longton  |
|Valley   |
|Valley   |
 ---------
```

Comment: Hint:  `TRIM(TRIM(TRIM(TRIM( . . .))))`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff works like charm. Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: Yeah, it's like a hair trimmer :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff are you going for answer or can i post it ?

Comment: Note that Gordon's answer can trim leading SOUTH EAST but not trailing SOUTH EAST, or vice versa. (Depending on TRIM order.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.. this will work for you any way..

```
select 
trim(TRIM(BOTH 'South' FROM TRIM(BOTH 'North' FROM TRIM(BOTH 'East' FROM TRIM(BOTH 'West' FROM town))))) from tbl
```

or more specified

```
select trim(case 
when position('North' in town) > 0 then TRIM(BOTH 'North' FROM town) 
when position('South' in town) > 0 then TRIM(BOTH 'South' FROM town) 
when position('East' in town) > 0 then TRIM(BOTH 'East' FROM town) 
when position('West' in town) > 0 then TRIM(BOTH 'West' FROM town) end)
from tbl
```

Comment: The `position` check is just an additional overhead

Comment: We can also write this `select trim(TRIM(BOTH 'South' FROM TRIM(BOTH 'North' FROM TRIM(BOTH 'East' FROM TRIM(BOTH 'West' FROM town))))) from tb`

Comment: This would be a better answer